# I'm currently making an Autoclicker and so far it's been a semi success. I need help introducing a toggle key

Tags: c++, winapi

At the moment I'm trying to add a toggle key and make it hold to click, so that when I toggle it and hold down left click, it starts clicking. Currently it boots up and when I center the CPS it clicks, but it doesn't stop. It'll click continuously.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;


int x = 0, y = 0, cps;
bool click = false;

void Menu()
{
    cout << "Add CPS (click per second):" << endl;
    cin >> cps;
}
void Clicker()
{
    while (1)
    {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON)) 
        {
            click = true;
        }

        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RBUTTON)) 
        {
            click = false;
        }

        if (click == true)
        {
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, x, y, 0, 0);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, x, y, 0, 0);
            Sleep(1000 / cps);
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    Menu();
    Clicker();
}
```

Comment: The code in the scope of `if (click == true)` will be executed unconditionally if `click` was set to true once. You may need to put another condition to tell if `if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON)) ` or `if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RBUTTON))` was happening immediately before.

Comment: Just a heads up: the cps won’t be 100% accurate because the program has to take time before the sleep function. Try testing out how long it takes or use a tool to find out how long the loop takes without the sleep function

Comment: Tip: `if (x == true)` can almost always be replaced with `if (x)`.

Comment: Also, a key is down if and only if GetAsyncKeyState returns a **negative** value. Win32 programming isn't simple, and perhaps your expectations of how much learning is required will need to be recalibrated.

Comment: Why so many auto-clickers? Every day it's a new auto-clicker.

Comment: This boils down to failing to read documentation, e.g. the documentation for [mouse_event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mouse_event) notes: *"This function has been superseded. Use `SendInput` instead."*

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following code to see if it helps:

```
void Clicker()
{
    while (1)
    {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) & 0x8000 && !click) //Capture that auto click start condition.
        {
            click = true;
        }
        else
        {
            click = false;
        }

        while (click)
        {
            if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RBUTTON) & 0x8000) //Capture the stop condition.
            {
                break;
            }
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, x, y, 0, 0);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, x, y, 0, 0);
            Sleep(1000 / cps);
        }
    }
}
```

[GetAsyncKeyState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate#return-value) Return Value:

> If the most significant bit is set, the key is down.

Comment: You posted a link to documentation that explains, how to determine, whether a key is pressed. You failed to apply that logic when trying to determine, whether a key isn't pressed.

Comment: @IInspectable I use `GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) & 0x8000` to check the most significant bit, if it is set indicate the key is down (pressed) whereas the key is up (isn't pressed).

Comment: Presumably, your second check is meant to determine, whether the key has been released (`//Capture the stop condition.`). That check, however, only reliably evaluates to `true`, if the key is **pressed**. [The behavior of the least significant bit of the return value is retained strictly for compatibility with 16-bit Windows applications (which are non-preemptive) and **should not be relied upon.**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate#remarks)

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks for pointing out. I forgot to correct the second check. I have updated it.