# Simulate leftclicks only while holding the leftclick button

Tags: c++, winapi

Im VERY new to coding and Im trying to create an autoclicker that clicks aslong as im holding my left mouse button.

this is what i've tried but i dont know how to make it stop clicking when i release the left mouse button.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int x=0, y=0, cps;
bool click=false;

void Menu()
{
    cout << "CPS: ";
    cin >> cps;
}
void Clicker()
{
    while (true)
    {
        if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) & 0x8000)
        {
            click = true;
        }


        while(click == true)
        {
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, x, y, 0 , 0);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, x, y, 0 , 0);
            Sleep(1000/cps);
        }


    }
}
int main()
{
    Menu();
    Clicker();
}
```

Comment: Look at your code. Ask yourself how, once click becomes true, it can subsequently become false. Ask your self how, once the body of the inner while loop is entered, it will ever exit.

Comment: You can check [this similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56741207/im-currently-making-an-autoclicker-and-so-far-its-been-a-semi-success-i-need) to see if it helps.

Comment: Hi Gurk, is the issue solved? If not, feel free let me know.

Comment: Yes! Switched to SendMessage instead and for the hold to click: 

if ((GetKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) & 0x80) != 0)
if ((GetKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) & 0x80) == 0)

Comment: @Gurk Glad to hear you got it working. You can share your solution as an answer and [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) it.

Answer (score 0):

what if you get rid of the click variable entirely:

```
void Clicker()
{
    while (true)
    {
        if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) & 0x8000)
        {
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, x, y, 0 , 0);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, x, y, 0 , 0);
            Sleep(1000/cps);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm. You should also set click to false at the beginning of your while(true) block

Comment: it doesnt click now